# Ext.form.Panel has no method 'getEl'

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

When I execute the below code, i can see an exception in my chrome logged like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getEl'

```
var search = new Ext.form.Panel({
    renderTo: 'pan',
    title: 'Basic Panel',
    collapsible:true,
    width: 400,
    defaults: {width: 230},
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    //layout: 'form',
    frame:true,
    items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Username',
            name: 'username',
            id: 'username',
            allowBlank:false
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'password',
           inputType:'password',
            allowBlank:false
        },

        {
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'firstname',
           inputType:'text',
            allowBlank:false
        }, 
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'lastname',
           inputType:'text',
            allowBlank:false
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'E-Mail Address',
            name: 'email',
           vtype:'email',

           allowBlank:false
        },

        {
            fieldLabel: 'State',
            name: 'state',
           allowBlank:false
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'City',
            name: 'city',
           allowBlank:false
        }, 
       {
            fieldLabel: 'Country',
            name: 'country',
           allowBlank:false
        }, 
        {
            inputType: 'hidden',
            id: 'submitbutton',
            name: 'myhiddenbutton',
            value: 'hiddenvalue'
        }

    ],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function() {
            search.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 'FormServlet';
            search.getForm().getEl().dom.method = 'POST';
            search.getForm().submit();
        }
    }]
```

I have defined the servlet in the web.xml file which contains the name, class and url.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it that complicated. I guess ExtJS overrides your settings or didn't use them at all cause you didn't used the appropriate config properties to set this.

Here are the API links for both

- **[method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-method)**
- **[url](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-url)**

Here is your demo code extended with these

```
var search = new Ext.form.Panel({
    renderTo: 'pan',
    title: 'Basic Panel',
    collapsible:true,
    width: 400,
    defaults: {width: 230},
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    url: 'FormServlet', // you can fix a parameter like this : FormServlet?action=create
    action: 'POST',
    frame:true,
    items: [
         //....
    ],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function() {
            search.getForm().submit();
        }
    }]
```

Or do it this way to be more flexible

```
var search = new Ext.form.Panel({
    renderTo: 'pan',
    title: 'Basic Panel',
    collapsible:true,
    width: 400,
    defaults: {width: 230},
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    url: 'FormServlet', 
    action: 'POST',
    frame:true,
    items: [
         //....
    ],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function() {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url : 'FormServlet',
                method:'POST', 
                params : {
                    yourParam: Ext.encode(form.getValues())
                },
                scope : this,
                //method to call when the request is successful
                success : this.onLoginSuccess,
                //method to call when the request is a failure
                failure : this.onLoginFailure
            });
        }
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the 1st example you posted and got this: `The requested resource (/Demo/jsp/FormServlet) is not available.` The servlet is present under the src folder, package name com.controller. But looking at the error, it seems like the servlet is searched under the jsp folder present under web content which is not correct. I tried a few options for replacing the url  such as: url: /Demo/scr/com.controller.FormServlet but it did not worked. Please help me with the value to be passed to the url.

Comment: @user182944 Take a Look at the Folder structure, you may need to navigate back first. You can archive this with '..' instead of a foldername like '../scr/com.controller.FormSrtvlet

Comment: when i check the properties of FormServlet.java, i got the path. In the url, i matched the same url with this: `../src/com/controller/FormServlet` but still it did not worked......Not sure what exactly the url is expecting :(

Comment: @user182944
Well, I guess it is no ExtJS problem anymore. And I am not used to servlets. Maybe you should repost this as servlet access problem or look what google gives you. Or try around directly on the URL in your browser to figure out the correct one. Again I never used servlets, so this is just a guess.

Comment: ok thats fine. I also believe that this problem is resolved :) thanks a lot. Can you please explain what is the use of `Ext.Ajax.request` and `params` of your second example?

Comment: @user182944 You just build up the request by yourself which allows you to wrap the whole form into one param which then can be desrialized to a approporiate object on serverside. With still the ability to send more params as within the form itself.

Comment: @user182944 Well, nice when your problem is solved :) So you could mark this question as answered, as I too guess it is ;)